# Created table from code behind not editable asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have a question. Is asp textbox not editable on a `<table>` created from code behind?

```
display = display & "<tr><td><asp:TextBox ID='TextBox1' class='bootstrap-tagsinput form-control' style='background: transparent;' data-role='tagsinput' runat='server'>" & gr2.Rows(k).Cells(0).Text & "</asp:TextBox></td></tr>"
```

When my I run my web page I can see the table being created but I am not able to edit the textbox inside.

This is my output:

[image]

But I did put a bootstrap class that makes the value inside the textbox will become a tagbox so I can edit like clicking the x to close the tag. But I'm not able to do it because the textbox seems to be not editable

It should look like this:
[image]

I hope someone has an idea on this. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot add an ASP.NET WebControl as is shows in your code. I’ll post an answer how you can achieve what you want (If I well understand)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is better you add a HtmlTable as an WebControl (or treat the existing HtmlTable by code behind) then add a TextBox inside (in your cell) as WebControl.
Doing that you can have full control by code behind .

However if you want to add a HTML element as a String source (literally)  in your code you can try as follows:

```
   display &= "<tr>" &
                     " <td> " &
                     " <input  type='text' id='TextBox1' value='" & gr2.Rows(k).Cells(0).Text & "' class='bootstrap-tagsinput form-control' style='background: transparent;' data-role='tagsinput' />" &
                     " </td>" &
               "</tr>"
```

Comment: THIS WORKED! I have another question. How can I retrieve the value of this input type? Thanks!

Comment: Yes. How can I get the values of the `<input type='text'/>` because even I put `runet='server'` I still can't call it's ID because it is not declared in the front end

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, to have full control by code behind you need to create this control by code behind.
Adding `runat=”server”` does not change the state of control as those controls l(with attribute `runat=”server”`) to be accessible by code behind need to be declared on Page not in code Behind as String.
You can create this controls in code behind `Dim mTxtBox As TextBox = New TextBox` then `myTable.Rows(1).Cells(2).Controls.Add(mTxtBox)` or  something like that.

Comment: I have already solve this. I used Javascript to get the values of the `<input type="text"/>`

Comment: Seems a valid way :)